# Why doesn't the button change color? (how to change html element's class)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an website with bootstrap and stuff, and I want to change a class for elements. I saw my code is not working, so I made an example to see where I'm wrong. I know I can solve it easily with django, but I want to know why my code doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .blue{
        background-color: blue
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type ="button" id="btn1" class = "blue" onclick="clicked()">hello</button>
    <script>
        function clicked(){
            document.getElementByid("btn1").className = "green"
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

after clicking the button, the button remains blue.
thank you for helping.

Comment: Check your console (hit F12 on Windows, Opt+Cmd+I on Mac). You have a typo. `getElementByid` should be `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error ( or typo ) in your code. You were using `document.getElementByid` with a small `i` while the valid function has a capital `I` i.e. `document.getElementById`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .blue{
        background-color: blue
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type ="button" id="btn1" class = "blue" onclick="clicked()">hello</button>
    <script>
        function clicked(){
            document.getElementById("btn1").className = "green"
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For typo related answers please use the comment section

Comment: @user2181397 sorry, I had actually copied the code to Code Snippet expecting some other issues.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj wow thank you very much! sorry for being such an idiot.